# Form Data from react cannot reach the backend (node.js)

Tags: reactjs, node.js, cors, mern

I don't know what I am doing wrong but my req.body when using FormData is null. When I am sending it normally as a json object it receives it but for some reason not Form Data

This is my code in the frontend

```
    const handleTweetSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
    
        // Construct FormData object
        const formData = new FormData();
        // Append JSON data
        formData.append('tweet', tweetObj.tweet);
        formData.append('gif', tweetObj.gif);
        formData.append('poll', JSON.stringify(tweetObj.poll));
        formData.append('emoji', tweetObj.emoji);
        formData.append('schedule', tweetObj.schedule);
        // Append image file
        formData.append('image', tweetObj.image);
    
        try {
            // Access the token from local storage
            const token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')).token;
            // Set the token in the header
            instance.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`;
            // Send the request to the backend
            const response = await instance.post(requests.addTweet, formData, {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data', // Set content type to multipart/form-data
                },
            });
            // Handle response
            setTweets((prevTweets) => {
                return [{ tweet: response.data.tweet, userDetails: userProfileObj }, ...prevTweets];
            });
            // Reset tweetObj state
            setTweetObj({
                tweet: '',
                image: '',
                gif: '',
                poll: {
                    question: '',
                    options: ['', ''],
                },
                emoji: null,
                schedule: null,
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error submitting tweet:', error);
        }
    };
```

In the backend

```
const createTweet = async (req, res) => {
    
    const { tweet, gif, poll, emoji, schedule } = req.body;
    console.log(req.body)
    const imageUrl = req.file ? req.file.path : null;
    // get the token from the request header
    const token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
    // decode the token to get the user id
    const decodedToken = jwt.decode(token);
    const username = decodedToken.id;
```

The req.body returns empty {}.

I dont know if my cors setup or configuration in general is the problem. So i will attach that as well: (Removed the part which might not be relevant)

```
const express = require('express');
const helmet = require('helmet');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const app = express();
const PORT = 8080; //USE env file later
const SOCKET_PORT = 3001;
require('dotenv').config();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const { Server } = require('socket.io');
const http = require('http'); // Import http module
const { createSocketServer } = require('../sockets/socket');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')




//const tweetServices = require('../services/tweet.services')

// mongodb connection 
try {
    mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/Twitter");
    logger.info("Connected to MongoDB");
} catch (error) {
    logger.error("Error connecting to MongoDB" + error);
}

// Middleware + Route Registration
const registerCoreMiddleWare = async () => {
    try {
        app.use(cors({
            origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
            credentials: true,
        }));
        app.use(
            session({
                secret: '64534847638dgfhjvfgdyucgt78r6g', 
                resave: false,
                saveUninitialized: true, 
                cookie: {
                    secure: false, 
                    httpOnly: true,
                },
            })
        );
        app.use(express.json());
        app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
        app.use(morgan('combined', { stream: logger.stream }));

        app.use(helmet());
        app.use(healthCheck);
        // app.use(uploadMiddleware);

        app.use('/auth', authRoutes);
        app.use('/profile', profileRoutes);
        app.use('/tweet', tweetRoutes)
        app.use('/chat', chatRoutes);
        app.use('/search', searchRoutes);
        app.use('/settings', settingsRoutes);

        
    //    chat using Socket.io
        createSocketServer(io);
    // Route registration

        app.use(notFound);



        logger.info("Done registering all middlewares and routes")

    } catch (error) {
        logger.error(error, 'Error registering middlewares and routes' + JSON.stringify(error, undefined, 2));
    }
};




// error handler function to be used in the main
const handleError = () => {
    process.on("uncaughtException", (error) => {
        logger.error(error, `Uncaught Exception occured : ${JSON.stringify(error.stack)}`);
        process.exit(1);
    });
}





// start server 
const startApp = async () => {
    try {
        // start by running the middleware registration
        await registerCoreMiddleWare();
        // start the server
        server.listen(SOCKET_PORT, () => {
            console.log('Socket listening on', SOCKET_PORT);
        });

        app.listen(PORT, () => {
            console.log('main server listening on', PORT);
        });
        handleError();

    }catch(err){
        logger.err(
            `startup:: Error while booting the application: ${JSON.stringify(
                err,
                undefined,
                2
            )}`
        );
        throw err;
    }
};




module.exports = { startApp };
```

I was sending the data NOT as a fromdata before, but i need to send image file to the backend for which i realise i need formData.

Comment: A few things I noticed:
1. I don't see bodyPaser being used in the Express app.
2. Formdata needs to be attached as the request `body` as many things are unclear in `instance` and `instance.post`